# On track Prerequisite for Statistics and Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I do not really have a solid mathematical background because of the range of courses i had back in high school/university that wasn't really scientific oriented. Presently i am doing an MSc in Computer Science which is going pretty well and almost completed but somehow, i have this nemesis course that deals with Poisson processes, Bernoulli, Markov chains and Branching process.The whole class(formulas) sounds Chinese to me although i am able to get the concepts.

So i will like to ask :

If you met this course today with no mathematical background, how will you approach it ? I have time to get back to the basics ! I just need to know a clear path before i start hitting the books.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Check the sylabi for your first courses, look at their webpages (or old homework, exams, lecture notes, ...). Grab copies of the textbooks. Ask the teachers.

This is an important question, but without detailed knowledge of what the classes will demand of you, and of your background, this is impossible to answer in any meaningful way. That is something only you (or you together with older students, or an advisor from the faculty) can answer.